# How to add an arrow between two edges in a graph?

Tags: arrows, graphs

How to make this type of diagram? I'm using tkz-graph, but I can't find a way to add this vertical arrow.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier to help you when we already see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick solution using `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
        \node (B) at (3,0) {$\bullet$};
        \draw [->, bend right] (B) to node [auto, swap] {$1_\bullet$} (A) ;
        \draw [->, bend left] (B) to node [auto] {$t(h)$} (A) ;
        \path (B) to node {$\Downarrow h$} (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This helps me today. Thx